# $f(x)+(f(x))^3=x \ \ $ Prove that $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, so that $f(x)+(f(x))^3=x \space,\space \forall x\in \Bbb R. \space\space\space (*)$

Prove that $f(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$

Suggestion: Show that $f(x+x^3)=x$

My attempt of a solution:

Given the rule for $f$ at $(*)$, we know it is nonempty, therefore exists $x_1\in \Bbb R$ for some $c\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x_1)=c$, then we can replace this result in $(*)$.$$f(x_1)+(f(x_1))^3=x_1 \\
c+c^3=x_1 \\
f(c+c^3)+(f(c+c^3))^3=c+c^3$$
Then I define the function $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, \space\space g(x)=x+x^3$ which is surjective, and compose it with $f$, so now I have the function $f(g(x)):\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, and $f(g(x))=f(x+x^3)$. Now I want to say that $f(x+x^3)=x$, but I am aware my arguments aren't enough to claim that as a truth. If it was true, then it is not difficult to prove that $f(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$

How can I improve/complete my proof? Is there any other way? How could I find a closed form for $f$?

Comment: Hint: $f(x)$ is the inverse function to $g(t)=t+t^3$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$? Do you mean $f(x)=x \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$? Or that $\operatorname{Img}(f)=\mathbb{R}$? This is a pretty serious abuse of notation.

Comment: @K.defaoite It means a real input produces a real output on function f.

Comment: @K.defaoite I don't think this is so bad: if $f:X\to Y$ is a map of sets, the standard convention is that $f(X)\subseteq Y$ denotes the set theoretic image. So, $f(\Bbb{R})=\{y\in \Bbb{R}: \text{there exists}\: x \:\text{with}\: f(x)=y\}$.

Comment: Ok thanks all for the clarification. Please excuse my rudeness.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: The function $G(y)=y +y^3$ is continuous and takes any real value in its domain. You have $G\circ f(x)= x$ for all $x$. $G$ is injective in $(-\infty,0]$ where it takes any negative value. Similarly, $G$ is injective in[ $0,\infty)$ where it takes any nonnegative value

Comment: $G'(y)=1+3y^{2} >0$ so $G$ is strictly increasing and injective on the whole real line.